# Converting US(default) date format to UK

Tags: vba, excel

For example:

```
Sub DateFormat()

Dim myDate As Date
myDate = DateValue("12/5/2012")
myDate1 = Format(myDate, "dd-mmm-yy")
MsgBox (myDate1)

End Sub
```

Excel VBA is following US date format, which will come out with 5-Dec-2012. I am here to ask if it is possible to add some codes, which they are meant to set the whole VBA codes relating to date to follow UK format.

Is there any possible to localize my VBA code using my regional setting in my computer? My computer has a regional setting following UK date format.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use DateSerial(yyyy, mm, dd) instead of DateValue(string)?

Comment: 1) declare your variables; `myDate1` needs a declaration and an explicit type. 2) treat dates as dates, write them to cells as dates, and apply number formatting accordingly. Treating dates as strings is the path to endless pain and sorrow. 3) drop the parentheses on that `MsgBox` call, that space between `MsgBox` and `(` is the VBE telling you "I'll take this expression, evaluate it, and then pass the result `ByVal` to the procedure you're invoking" - you'll run into issues (both at compile-time and at run-time) one day or another with these parentheses.

Comment: Format will do what you ask it to do, VBA will not default to UK. What is the exact output you are looking for?

Comment: Also FYI `#2012/05/12#` is a *date literal* in VBA. There *shouldn't* be a need to convert from a hard-coded string, ever.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon The correct format is `#MONTH/DAY/YEAR#`

Comment: @JohnyL Sure, for US values of "correct". #OnlyInUSA. Also the VBE automatically mangles it into the correct format. I *know* what's what in an ISO format, and so does the VBE when it americanizes the date literal. So, entering ISO formats and letting the VBE swap everything as it sees fit is the safest way to enter a non-ambiguous date literal.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Letting VBE swapping positions could bring confusion to user, especially newbie one, so I would strongly advise to understand and use the correct representation *in the first place*.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree then - US date format is ambiguous and confusing to literally everyone in the rest of the world, and arguably shouldn't even exist. And the VBE understands ISO format correctly 100% of the time, and people not familiar with US date format get ISO format correctly 100% of the time. Sometimes, maybe, once in a while, the non-US way just makes total and complete sense. Like, when date formats are concerned.